# Laravel 4 Resource Routes and Authentication

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm not sure of the terminology I should be using so please bear with me, hopefully if I haven't got this right, someone might be able to tease the right question out!

ok.. so I have

```
 Route::resource('gameworlds', 'GameworldsController');
```

This is fine. There are views for create, edit, index and show as you would expect and they all work fine. What I would like to do is only allow access to the "create" part when a user is logged in.

For example.. I have another route in my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('dashboard', array('before' => 'auth', function()
    return View::make('dashboard/index');
 }));
```

This works as expected, but I don't really understand how I can put similar code in the resource route for the "create" part only. Can someone explain that part to me please?

Many thanks.

DS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you don't need a filter, but instead you can use the Auth check method to check if user is logged in or not:

```
if (Auth::check()) { //Logged in }
```

In your controller method to make sure the user is logged in, and if he isn't you can do a redirect, like:

```
return Redirect::to('user/login');
```

However if you want to use a filter you could use the beforeFilter method in the __construct of your controller, like this:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('on' => array('create')));
    }
```

Comment: perfect. thankyou. i don't really understand the times when you would use either. i'm a newbie so perhaps I will get the hold of it soon. in the meantime I'll have a read at some more material. many thanks.